# java.lang.NullPointerException on explicit wait

Tags: c#, selenium, remotewebdriver

I am trying to loop through and click on a number of buttons on a web page. My code first checks for the number of the elements on the page, then loops through and clicks each one.

This worked for the first loop, but then I got an `Element Not Found` exception on the second loop. This is because when the button is clicked the element disappears from the page and the DOM changes. I then read that an explicit wait will force Selenium to repoll the DOM. So I added the explicit wait.

But now I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` on the very first loop at the `wait.Until` line.

The driver is a `RemoteWebDriver` if that makes any difference.

```
var elements = new List<IWebElement>();
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait=TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
elements.AddRange(driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//button[contains(@data-cancelref,'outgoing_requests')]")));

if(!elements.Any()) {
    return;
}

int loop = elements.Count-1;
for(int i = 0; i<loop; i++) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//button[contains(@data-cancelref,'outgoing_requests')]")));
    var button = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(@data-cancelref,'outgoing_requests')]"));
    button.Click();
    Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(2000, 4000));
}

driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait=TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
```

Stack Trace:

```
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.get_Displayed()
at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.ExpectedConditions.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<ElementIsVisible>b__0(IWebDriver driver)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
at _Common.FDriver.Clean(IWebDriver driver, String prox, Int32 timeout, Boolean& success) in C:\_Common\FDriver.cs:line 727
```

Line 727 is the For statement

Comment: I think you have stale elements in the list of "elements" you loaded. does FindElements(...).First() work if you move the find into the loop?

Comment: The List of Elements is only used to get the number of the elements to put in the loop. Each loop I am simply trying to find the first element and click on it. And repeat. Which is what the explicit wait is for; to refresh the DOM.

Comment: The Implicit wait is turned off before the loop, specifically because I am using the explicit wait and ensuring that I don't mix them. So I'm not sure what point you are trying to make.

Comment: How does the stack trace look like?

Comment: Stack trace added. Sorry, no idea why it wont format properly.

Comment: It's weird to say c# programs throw a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. What is the exact exception `UnpackAndThrowOnError`  throws?

Comment: That is literally the exception. Exact case and all. And yes, confused the hell out of me too.

Comment: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.cs#L1359-L1454 There's not a branch it will throw an exception of type `java.lang.NullPointerException` though ..

Comment: Can you warp `wait.Until` in a try-catch block with `catch(Exception e)` and debug to see what `e` is?

Comment: @Ken Kin. I've provided the Message and StackTrace. There is nothing for InnerException. Is there other info I can check for?

Comment: @MarkMasic: The *exception type*. `java.lang.NullPointerException` is unlikely a type which is derived from `Exception` in c# that `RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError` would throw.

Comment: @Ken Kin. Ok, but then where does it come from? I don't get it either. I'm not making this up. It's really got me confused.

Comment: @MarkMasic: try-catch on `wait.Until` and run in debug mode; set a breakpoint on `catch` then you should see.

Comment: @Ken Kin Ok I did that. There is a lot of data there. Is there anything in particular I should be looking for?

Comment: @MarkMasic: I'm just wondering the *exception type*. The exception object *type* of the thrown exception, not its message or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this more complicated than it needs to be. From what you have stated, each time to click a button it disappears from the page. Because of this, you don't need to (and don't want to) loop through the elements with a counter because on each loop the collection gets smaller.

This is the logic:

1. You scrape the page to get the current collection of buttons
2. You click the first button

You repeat these steps until there are no more buttons.

```
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> elements = GetElements();
while (elements.Any())
{
    elements.ElementAt(0).Click();
    elements = GetElements();
}
```

I put the code to get the elements in a separate function. You don't have to but I think it makes the code a little cleaner.

```
public IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> GetElements()
{
    return new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.XPath("//button[contains(@data-cancelref,'outgoing_requests')]")));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried it and it throws that same exception as my code does at GetElements(). Could this be caused by the Remote Driver Service that I am using? I can't think of anything else that might cause this error.

Comment: My guess is that you have some driver instance somewhere that is declared separately and never set to anything so it's null. I would start commenting out code until you get down to exactly what is needed to repro the error. Then start from scratch and step through it looking for null variables or anything that doesn't make sense.